# CakePHP not saving data to database

Tags: cakephp, save

I am currently trying to save various records into the same model.

I have read the docs concerning format of data, and my custom array of data conforms to this.

This is my function:

```
$k = 0;
foreach($this->request->data['FileData'] as $data) {
    $name = substr($data['name'],0,strpos($data['name'],'_'));
    $ext = substr($data['name'],strrpos($data['name'],'.')+1);
    $display_name = str_replace('.'.$ext,'',str_replace($name . '_','',$data['name']));
    $Clinic = $this->Clinic->find('first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Clinic.name' => strtoupper($data['owner'])
            ),
            'fields' => array('id')
        )
    );
    $Data['Upload'][$k]['clinic_id'] = $Clinic['Clinic']['id'];
    $Data['Upload'][$k]['file_name'] = $data['name'];
    $Data['Upload'][$k]['display_name'] = $display_name;
    $Data['Upload'][$k]['extension'] = $ext;
    $k++;
}
$this->Upload->create();
if ($this->Upload->saveMany($Data,array('deep'=>true))) { ** READ BELOW
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The upload has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The upload could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
```

I get no validation errors. The data passed to this function, looks like follows:

```
array(
    'Upload' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'clinic_id' => '72',
            'file_name' => 'MAHLUNGULU CLINIC_0_Guide_Tax_Season_2012_Insert_Afrikaans.pdf (6).pdf',
            'display_name' => '0_Guide_Tax_Season_2012_Insert_Afrikaans (6)',
            'extension' => 'pdf'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'clinic_id' => '79',
            'file_name' => 'ZAMA ZAMA CLINIC_1377256_515345465221385_1613340746_n.jpg',
            'display_name' => '1377256_515345465221385_1613340746_n',
            'extension' => 'jpg'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'clinic_id' => '72',
            'file_name' => 'MAHLUNGULU CLINIC_07reader.xlsx',
            'display_name' => '07reader',
            'extension' => 'xlsx'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'clinic_id' => '79',
            'file_name' => 'ZAMA ZAMA CLINIC_13-disturbed-i_still_havent_found_what_im_looking_for.mp3',
            'display_name' => '13-disturbed-i_still_havent_found_what_im_looking_for',
            'extension' => 'mp3'
        )
    )
)
```

(I know this is weird data, but it's test data)

** I have tried the following methods of saving, all of them fail:

```
$this->Upload->saveMany($Data,array('deep',true));
$this->Upload->saveMany($Data['Upload'],array('deep',true));
$this->Upload->save($Data);
$this->Upload->save($Data['Upload']);
$this->Upload->saveAll($Data);
$this->Upload->saveAll($Datap['Upload']);
```

None of them work. Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: DarkRanger i edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data['modelname']['dbfieldname']`
`$this->modelname->save(data);`

Comment: So I have to do `x` amount of seperate saves and can't save all of them at once?

Comment: Can we see your model? Does it work when you try saving a single record?

I would also suggest using CakePHP's testing suite and the debug bar plugin for trying to analyse whats going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting I look at my model. Turns out one of the fields was set up as datetime (for some absurd reason) and as such, failed because it received a string. It works now. What I don't get is WHY it wasn't returned when I did a $this->validationErrors().

Answer (score 1):

Your post data should be in the format cake expects, eg: `data[Model][some_field]` `$this->modelname->save(data);`

`*EDIT*`

Looked at it a bit better, i think your array is in the wrong order, it should be:

```
$Data[$k]['Upload']['display_name'] = $display_name;
$Data[$k]['Upload']['extension'] = $ext;
```

i.e. the entries in the numerical index are Model.key.

... reading the doc a bit, i see:

```
 For saving multiple records of single model, $data needs to be a numerically indexed      array of records like this:

 $data = array(
     array('title' => 'title 1'),
     array('title' => 'title 2'),
);


It is also acceptable to have the data in the following format:

$data = array(
     array('Article' => array('title' => 'title 1')),
     array('Article' => array('title' => 'title 2')),
);
```

From [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) . So you need either no Model designator at all or it has to be after the numerical index like in the example I gave. Good luck. If it doesn't work crank up the debugging in core.php and look at the generated SQL (if any).

Comment: So I have to do `x` amount of seperate saves and can't save all of them at once?

Comment: `$this->modelname->saveAll(data);`

Comment: Sorry about that, try this `$this->Upload->saveMany($Data['Upload'], array('deep' => true));`

Comment: For my issue it was that for whatever reason the generated form was changing the model to "Post" instead of my model. Simply changing the line `$this->Form->create('Post');` to `$this->Form->create();` solved my issue!